Can I split the rendering in external displays between the GPU and CPU?
If MacBook Pro with an M4 chip has a GPU chip that is only compatible with two external displays, can I have two external displays rendered with the GPU and one additional display rendered via Display Link? Or once I add the third I am only able to render them all via Display Link (utilizing the CPU)?

A DisplayLink USB adapter is a video device of its own - it's like adding another video card (with limited feature set) internally.
Your GPU-connected video still runs the same as before.
